# Get pairs of two records with highest average grade

Tags: mysql, sql, join, average, database-partitioning

I want to calculate the average grade of every record, and then get the two records with the highest average grade, per category.

My `grade` table looks like this:

```
userid | recordid | grade
123    | 1        | 8
123    | 2        | 1
123    | 3        | 3
123    | 4        | 6
121    | 1        | 3
121    | 2        | 7
121    | 3        | 1
121    | 4        | 8
124    | 1        | 6
124    | 2        | 8
124    | 3        | 9
124    | 4        | 5
```

And the `record` table like this:

```
id | userid | name | category | year
1  | 101    | Foo  | FooCat   | 2021
2  | 102    | Bar  | FooCat   | 2021
3  | 103    | Foos | BarCat   | 2021
4  | 104    | Bars | BarCat   | 2021
```

The result will look like this:

```
id | name | category | grade_avg
4  | Bars | BarCat   | 6.3
1  | Foo  | FooCat   | 5.7
2  | Bar  | FooCat   | 5.3
3  | Foos | BarCat   | 4.3
```

I'm currently using this SQL query:

```sql
SELECT S.id
     , S.name
     , S.category
     , AVG(IB.grade) AS grade_avg
  FROM 
     (SELECT id
           , name
           , category
           , year
           , row_number() over (partition by category) as r 
        FROM records) S
    JOIN grades IB 
        ON IB.recordid = S.id
 WHERE S.r < 3 
   AND S.year=2021
 GROUP 
    BY IB.recordid
 ORDER 
    BY grade_avg DESC
```

The grouping does work perfectly, but the grades at partitioning are not sorted by their average grade, so you just get the first 2 records per category.

What is the best query to get the result I want to achieve? This is an example, I will translate it to my own use, so that I learn to use the given SQL example better.

Comment: You want the average of the two highest grades?

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, I want to get the 2 records with the highest average grades, and then grouped by category. So that you get 2 records for every category.

Comment: It took kind of a long time just to figure out what you're asking. It would be helpful if your sample dataset were altered to match your actual requirements. In the example dataset add more than two records for each and then change the grades so that a given user is getting an average of different values. This way we know what you're asking and can test our answers before making them.

Comment: @AltimusPrime Will work on that.

Comment: Thank you for the updates. The record table's userid's don't match the grade table's userid's. Does it matter?

Comment: @AltimusPrime I did that on purpose. The grades are given by other users (with higher permissions) then the users who add the records.

Comment: So then it's not relevant to the aggregation? Also, I thought you only wanted the two highest grades to be averaged, but 6.3 is an average of 5,6, and 8. Is that how it really should be?

Comment: @AltimusPrime The average of every record should be calculated, then it should limit to 2 records per category. So if you have 3 categories, you will get 6 records (assuming every category has 2 records).

Comment: @stijnbannink . . . Why do you have duplicate categories in the results?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know, because of bad design. The category is hard-coded at the moment.

Comment: 'The category is hard-coded at the moment' I have to check out. I'm pretty good with complex queries and even procedures when needed, but how can we give an answer to match your description if the example isn't even what you're asking for?

Comment: @AltimusPrime It is? There are 5 categories (other names, but that doesn't matter for the example), I've picked two and put them in my description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by taking [the answer of Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66920197/7972413) as my base, and change some things in it.

This is working for me:

```sql
SELECT name, category, avg(grade) AS grade_avg
FROM (SELECT name, category, avg(grade) AS grade_avg,
         row_number() over (partition by category ORDER BY grade_avg DESC) as r 
      FROM grades IB JOIN
            records I 
            ON IB.recordid = I.id 
      WHERE year = 2021
      GROUP BY id
   ) S 
WHERE S.r < 3 
ORDER BY grade_avg DESC
```

So I'm partitioning on the category (ordered by the average grade), grouping by the ID, and then ordering by the average grade.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you can use `row_number()` to enumerate the rows to get the two with the highest grade and then aggregate:

```
select name, category, avg(grade)
from (select g.*, r.name, r.category,
             row_number() over (partition by g.recordid order by g.grade desc) as seqnum
      from grades g join
           records r
           on g.recordid = r.id
      where r.year = 2021
     ) g
where seqnum <= 2
group by name, category;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a2a8e754653e87e3f9bcd0aac1efb77) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

Based on your results, you want just the overall average, not the average of the top two rows.  This is much simpler:

```
select r.name, r.category, avg(grade)
from grades g join
     records r
     on g.recordid = r.id
where r.year = 2021
group by r.name, r.category
```

Comment: Does show the correct data, but does not limit the amount of records per category to 2.

Comment: seqnum is always 1 for me, in every record.

Comment: The `row_number()` should be limiting the results.

Comment: I think the problem here is that it's not partitioning on the average grade, but on the grade. I get results with an incorrect average grade.

Comment: The second query does work, but it does not get the two highest grades PER category, so there is no way for me to limit (LIMIT 2 wouldn't work, because that's just the records with the highest grade).

Comment: Thanks for your help! Fixed it by tweaking some values. :)